# SQLAlchemy one to many relationship without child knowing

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have three models, foo1, foo2 and bar.

I am trying to create a one to many relationship from foo1 to bar and from foo2 to bar, completely independent of bar. Basically I need multiple one to many relationships from any model to bar, without telling bar about it.

I know you can do it with a one to one relationship:

```
bar_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("bar.id"))
bar = db.relationship("bar", uselist=False)
```

Any help would be appreciated.